# I have set of points like P1,P2,P3,....,Pn and each point has x and y as numbers. How can I do math to these points in python?

Tags: python

I have these points:

```
P1 = (1,2) = (1**2+2**2)**1/2 = 5**1/2  //this is how we can compute the point and so on for the rest. the ** means the power of.
P2 = (3,2)    //P2.x = 3 , P2.y = 2 and so on for the rest points
P3 = (1,1)    // P3.x= 1  , P3.y = 1
..
..
..
Pn = (m,k)



P= <P1(1,2),P2(3,2),P3(1,1),......,Pn(2,2)>
P
|P|= ((P1**2)+(P2**2)+.....+(Pn**2))**1/2     //the square root of the sum of square points
```

What is the best way to write python function for a distance from P1 to Pn? for those equations Sx and Sy

```
Sx = (P1.x)/|P| + (P2.x)/|P| + (P3.x)/|P| + ...... +(Pn.x)/|P| 
Sy = (P1.y)/|P| + (P2.y)/|P| + (P3.y)/|P| + ...... +(Pn.y)/|P|
```

form the above equations we will get point of S(Sx,Sy).
I tried my way I put x values in a list and y values in another list to slice it based on n value. so suppose you already have x, y values of P:

```
x = [1,3,1,.......,m]
y = [2,2,1, ......,k]
```

Comment: Whenever you have a bunch of numbers, the answer is always "use `numpy`"

Comment: Two reasonable options: make or use a `Point` class, or (more performant), use NumPy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure Python, you can create a `Point` class, and overload relevant operators:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def sqnorm(self):
        p = self * self
        return p.x + p.y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.sqnorm() + other

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x * other.x, self.y * other.y)
```

And a norm function:

```
def norm(points):
    return math.sqrt(sum(points))
```

Usage:

```
points = [Point(1,2), Point(3,2), Point(1,1)]

print(norm(points))
```

---

In NumPy,

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

points = np.concatenate((x, y), axis=1)

norm = np.sum(points**2)

Sx = x / norm
Sy = y / norm
```

Comment: what do u mean about other? and how can u deploy this equa:
Sx = (P1.x)/|P| + (P2.x)/|P| + (P3.x)/|P| + ...... +(Pn.x)/|P|  for n points

Comment: I defined the `__add__` and `__mul__` operators so that you can write `p1 + p2` to add points or `p * p` to square them. `other` refers to the second point you want to add/multiply with.

Comment: You can get `Sx` by computing `Sx = sum(p.x for p in points) / norm(points)`.

Comment: the p.x you mentioned is going to take x value from p(x,y)?

Comment: See my usage example. To create a point, you simply do: `p = Point(2, 3)`

Comment: It works fine but I need to work on lots of points. I have 2 columns and hundreds of rows in csv file of x and y points:I want to get that as: Points = [Point(1,3),Point(2,4),......] for that cvs file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156378/discussion-between-alsphere-and-mateen-ulhaq).

Comment: If you're working on a lot of points, it's probably better to use NumPy.

Comment: How that would be ?